# Позиционирование элемента слева с использованием float CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Столкнулась с проблемой, что на некоторых одинаковых страницах, текст с ссылкой уезжает направо.

Стили:

```
.foot {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Cкриншот (некорректно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Cкриншот (корректно)](https://ibb.co/z7W8p92)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам достаточно отказаться от [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/float) позиционирования, так как Вы хотите что бы элемент находился слева, что и так является его дефолтной позицией.

```
.foot {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Используя `float` Вы меняете его привычный flow, заставляя другие `inline` элементы его "обтекать".